# Is there a way to avoid refreshes of a page load in a web application?

Tags: html, http

I have a web application using Primefaces 8.0 and JSF 2.2 and the way I have users navigate to instances of the application is by an HTML page with links like the following:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="mynewwindow">Always opens in the same window</a>
```

This makes sure that if the user clicks the link a second time, it simply navigates to the tab they already have open. But the browser(chromium in this case) also forces a refresh of the tab every time this link is clicked! Is there any way to avoid this forced refresh?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for [Single-Page Applications](https://medium.com/@NeotericEU/single-page-application-vs-multiple-page-application-2591588efe58).

Comment: Look for caching... plain http issue